# Editing NSMutableArray of identical objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` of custom objects *(Subclasses from JSONModel)*, all the objects are identical. I'm copying a single object as many times I want to add it to the array *(If this method is wrong, kindly suggest the proper way).* When I edit/modify an object at some index, it tends to modify all the objects in that array.

I made a sample project that explains this issue and uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqoky4cjxjb2xyo/Trial.zip?dl=0).
Please advice solutions to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: add some code here...
u can use replaceObjectAtIndex of mutablearray to modify some object in it

Comment: Add your code where you replace the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your _iMember that you're having issues with you are just passing in the same pointer to the object twice, both are referring to the one object. If you want multiple versions of _iMember then you'll need to allocate them, or use copyWithZone (for a shallow copy) depending on the class or structure.

Comment: If I modify like, Member *_iMember2 = [_iMember copy]... will it fix?

Comment: It works.. But I don't understand... I tried the same with NSString... It replaced the first object alone.. Why not here?

Comment: How did you create those strings? That will be the reason.

Comment: Just NSString *xxx = @"sss"; for (..) {[somearray addObject:xxx];}
Today is the day, I learned the importance of 'copy'.. Thanks for that :)